# How to connect to localhost from virtualbox? (windows)

Tags: localhost, virtual-machine, virtualbox

My computer is running Win7 with IE11 and I wanted to be able to test visual studio web application in IE9. So, I downloaded an IE9 vhd from Microsoft and set it up on Oracle VM, but how would I go about being able to access my localhost from this virtual machine?

Answer (score 0):

You must put your guest and your host in the same network. You have some different ways to do this. VB allows you to create an internal network. Both, host and guest will have an IP for this network. Find out the IP of your host (type ipconfig in cmd). Open your guest's browser and in the URL type the IP of your host. This is how you access it. The main thing to do is to put host and guest in the same network.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is by using "Bridged Adapter" mode at you virtual box's network setting. Choose the the connection that you want to be bridged to, then setup you virtual machine's ip address to be at the same network as you host machine.

for more details, please read this page

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html